# Communicating with HTTP across processes in the same Docker container

Tags: http, docker, networking, localhost

I have 2 processes running in the same container, I want them to talk with HTTP. This container happens to be running in the same Docker network, but I don't think that should matter, but just in case it does, I just mentioned it.

I would assume these two processes can talk to each other via "localhost" but that does not seem to be the case. Is there some special hostname or ip I need to use to get these processes to be able to communicate with HTTP when they run in the same container?

Comment: Have you tried using docker -inspect container_name to get the address of the container, then use that IP address between processes?

Comment: You should be able to use `localhost` without a problem. If that's not working, you will need to update your question with substantially more detail: what processes are running? What is the output of `netstat -tlnp` (or the equivalent `ss` command) run *inside* the container?

Comment: @Mr Slim yeah I tried that..I know what the container name...@larks ok I will get that info, good to know that localhost should work

Comment: if you want to talk with HTTP, one process must be an HTTP server, the other an HTTP client. Which HTTP server are you using? Your own? Apache? Nginx? Tomcat?

Comment: In this case the server is just a node.js server